# display/merge multiple columns in a table as one column just separated by lines

Tags: excel, powerbi

Is there a way to display/merge multiple columns in a table as one column just separated by lines. More specifically, what I want is to display value for rows for different days of the week, and there are multiple such weeks in a year. 
Thus, for example, an engineer works on the week on 4th jan '16 from monday to sunday for some number of hours each day, then next week of Jnauary he works some different hours each day.
Thus, every week from Mon to Sun will have a different value for each day. I want to display these weekdays as a cluster so I see them together and not separate columns for every day.
I have attached a sample sheet.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU6fV.png)

Comment: Is this for an Excel table or a Power BI table?

Comment: This is for Power BI

Comment: You will (probably) need to re-shape your data. Something along the lines of a table with fields `Name`, `Location`, `WeekDate`, `Mo`, `Tu`...`Su`. Then you could have a calculated column of form `Days = IF(table[Mo]=1,"Mo, ","") && IF(table[Tu]=1,"Tu,","") && ... && IF(table[Su]=1,"Su,","")`